# Does the order of conditions in a WHERE clause affect MySQL performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say that I have a long, expensive query, packed with conditions, searching a large number of rows. I also have one particular condition, like a company id, that will limit the number of rows that need to be searched considerably, narrowing it down to dozens from hundreds of thousands.

Does it make any difference to MySQL performance whether I do this:

```
 SELECT * FROM clients WHERE 
       (firstname LIKE :foo OR lastname LIKE :foo OR phone LIKE :foo) AND 
       (firstname LIKE :bar OR lastname LIKE :bar OR phone LIKE :bar) AND 
       company = :ugh
```

or this:

```
 SELECT * FROM clients WHERE 
       company = :ugh AND
       (firstname LIKE :foo OR lastname LIKE :foo OR phone LIKE :foo) AND 
       (firstname LIKE :bar OR lastname LIKE :bar OR phone LIKE :bar)
```

Comment: MySQL also has `EXPLAIN <SELECT ...>` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: This section may help: [WHERE clause optomisations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, the order should not make a large difference. When finding which rows match the condition, the condition as a whole (all of the sub-conditions combined via boolean logic) is examined for each row.

Some intelligent DB engines will attempt to guess which parts of the condition can be evaluated faster (for instance, things that don't use built-in functions) and evaluate those first, and more complex (estimatedly) elements get evaluated later. This is something determined by the DB engine though, not the SQL.

Comment: I don't think you're right. Tables are not simply scanned through to evaluate conditions if not necessary. E.g., if an index exists for 'company'. The first subset selection is done using the index. If company wouldn't be evaluated first, the index couldn't be used anymore. However, a sophisticated DBMS should be able to decide which condition should be evaluated first to optimize the query.

Comment: P.S. (cannot edit my comment anymore): Of course you're right in you second section, but the statement "the condition as a whole ... is evaluated for each row" is what I doubt.

Comment: @chiccodoro: I think the optimizer takes care of that.

Comment: @chiccodoro: Sorry, bad wording on my part. Shouldn't be evaluated, should be more "examined". Evaluated implies that the value of each part is found, which wasn't what I was saying.

Comment: To allow optimization (usage of indexes) you may want to order your WHEREs right. For example, a LIKE should be on of your last conditions, and the first condition based on a index. I'm not sure which DB does which optimizations automatically, as this specific one is not well documented.

Answer (score 36):

[Here is a demo](http://rextester.com/HJGN96158) showing the order of WHERE clause conditions *can* make a difference due to short-circuiting. It runs the following queries:

```
-- query #1
SELECT myint FROM mytable WHERE myint >= 3 OR myslowfunction('query #1', myint) = 1;

-- query #2
SELECT myint FROM mytable WHERE myslowfunction('query #2', myint) = 1 OR myint >= 3;
```

The only difference between these is the order of operands in the `OR` condition.

`myslowfunction` deliberately sleeps for a second and has the side effect of adding an entry to a log table each time it is run. Here are the results of what is logged when running the two queries:

```
myslowfunction called for query #1 with value 1
myslowfunction called for query #1 with value 2
myslowfunction called for query #2 with value 1
myslowfunction called for query #2 with value 2
myslowfunction called for query #2 with value 3
myslowfunction called for query #2 with value 4
```

The above shows that a slow function is executed more times when it appears on the left side of an `OR` condition when the other operand isn't always true.

So IMO the answer to the question:

> Does the order of conditions in a WHERE clause affect MySQL performance?

is "Sometimes it can do."

Answer (score 8):

The order of columns in your where clause shouldn't really matter, since MySQL will optimize the query before executing it. But I suggest you read the chapter on [Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html) in the MySQL reference manual, to get a basic idea on how to analyze queries and tables, and optimize them if necessary.  Personally though, I would always try to put indexed fields before non-indexed fields, and order them according to the number of rows that they should return (most restrictive conditions first, least restrictive last).

Answer (score 5):

**Mathematically Yes** It has an effect. Not only in SQL Query. rather in all programming languages whenever there is an expression with `and` / `or` . 
There works a theory of Complete evaluation or partial evaluation.
If its an and query and first expression of `and` evaluates to false it will not check further. as anding false with anything yields false .
Similerly in an or expression if first one is true it will not check further.

Comment: They aren't the only choices. Some languages have short-circuit evaluation. Some promise to evaluate all of the expressions. Others have lazy evaluation, and only evaluate what they need in an undefined order. SQL (apparently) can choose its own order of evaluation for optimal short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

A sophisticated DBMS should be able to decide on its own which where condition to evaluate first. Some Databases provide tools to display the "strategy" how a query is executed. In MySQL, e.g. you can enter [`EXPLAIN` in front of a query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html). The DBMS then prints the actions it performed for executing the query, as e.g. index or full-table scan. So you could see at a glance whether or not it uses the index for 'company' in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

this shouldn't have any effect, but if you aren't sure, why don't you simply try it out? the order of where-clauses on an select from a single table makes no difference, but if you join multiple tables, the order of the joins could affect the performace (sometimes).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the order of the where clause has any impact. I think the MySQL query optimizer will reorganize where clauses as it sees fit so it filters away the largest subset first.

It's another deal when talking about joins. The optimizer tries to reorder here too, but doesn't always finds the best way and sometimes doesn't use indexes. SELECT STRAIGHT JOIN and FORCE INDEX let's you be in charge of the query.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't, the tables required are selected and then evaluated row by row. Order can be arbitrary.

Comment: This would be true for full-table-scans but gladly the database has seldom to perform such a inefficent way.
Mostly it will search in its (B-tree) index for entrys matching the criteria.

Comment: Then it has an effect, because if the B-tree for one condition is larger than the other, it will take longer to find it. Unless if mysql does an intersection for AND statements. Then no.

Comment: i just switched the order of 3 clauses I have and it made a difference. result was different data