# Mysql Query execute order

Tags: mysql

I have doubts regarding MySQL query executing order.

```
select * 
from  exa_ledger 
where examyear = '2011-11-1' 
  and academicbatch = '2010-6-1' 
  and courseid = '01'
```

In the query above, which condition is executed first? With condition I mean: Do checks start with `examyear`, `academicbatch` or `courseid`?

`exa_ledger` table has 120500 rows, and condition matchings are:

```
examyear - 60000 rows
academicbatch - 35000 rows
courseid - 10000 rows
```

How should i write the query for getting result faster?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a table schema and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for your query.

Comment: @Justin Vincent : any update on @ jcmeloni question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the order of conditions in a WHERE clause affect MySQL performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043042/does-the-order-of-conditions-in-a-where-clause-affect-mysql-performance)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on other requirements of your application you should create a composite index containing some or all of the fields that you have mentioned (but at the very least courseid since it has the smallest number of rows).