# Does the order of conditions make a performance difference in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a MySQL query like this, the table `PEOPLE` has about 2 million rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `PEOPLE` WHERE `SEX`=1 AND `AGE`=28;
```

The first condition will return 1 million rows, and the second condition may return 20,000 rows. From the local website, most developers said that it will cause a better affect to change the order of them. And they also said that It will cause a `2 million + 1 million + *10,000*` I/O time if change the order, while original query above will cause a `2 million + 20,000 + *10,000*` I/O time. It sounds make sense.

As we all know that MySQL has an internal query optimizer for such work. Does the order needs pay particular attention for optimal performance? I was totally confused.

PS: I noticed that there are some similar question asked already, but they are two or tree years ago, it seems better to ask again.

---

Thanks all noticed this question. This is a explain about why i ask again:

Before I ask this question, I run EXPLAIN for a couple of times. The answer is the order doesn't matter. But the Interviewer told me the order will make a difference performance, I want make it sure if there is something i missing.

Comment: This should make no difference. The optimizer should be smart enough to apply the most discriminative criterion first. If it's not, it's a bug...

Comment: You can easily test this, this question is not a good fit for stack overflow because so is for questions about code that you have and can't get to work. Not for theoretical questions.

Comment: @fge how can it know without scanning all records?

Comment: When you had typed in your title and pressed Tab to start typing the text, the **very first item** on the "This question may already have an answer" list was: [Does the order of conditions in a WHERE clause affect MySQL performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043042/does-the-order-of-conditions-in-a-where-clause-affect-mysql-performance) *"PS: I noticed that there are some similar question asked already, but they are two or tree years ago, it seems better to ask again."* Because you think MySQL has *regressed* in the meantime?

Comment: @JuanMendes index metadata; the cardinality, in this case. (those two columns _are_ indexed, right?)

Comment: @fge you'd need to index every possible value of age?

Comment: @JuanMendes no, of course not, the only values indexed are the values you actually enter ;) Which allows for fail-fast if an age is entered which does not exist

Comment: @fge Thanks for the explanation, don't know much about the inner workings of sql optimization. Had never heard of indexing cardinality, but it sure makes sense

Comment: @JuanMendes Unfortunately I don't have such large amounts of data for test, the problem is mentioned in an interview. And even though I have this large amount of data, I can not guarantee that all cases had tested. What i want to know is not a simple answer, I want to understand it in depth.

Comment: @Drazzi: no, the order doesn't matter, if you want to know what it will do _before_ it does it, run an `EXPLAIN`, and a query plan is created based on cardinality of indexes, which you can see with a `SHOW INDEXES FROM tablename;`

Comment: Answer is - no, the order doesn't matter. If you want to understand why and how and the depth of why the order doesn't matter - there's always the source available.

Comment: Actually, the source won't explain much if you don't know the theory behind it all. The theoretical relational database _has no notion of an index_.

Comment: @Wrikken Before I ask this question, I run `EXPLAIN` for a couple of times. The answer is the order doesn't matter. But the Interviewer told me the order will make a difference performance, I want make it sure if there is something i missing.

Comment: Your interviewer lied to you (on purpose?). Order does not matter, if it does, it's a bug in the database engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first understand a fundamental thing: in theory, a relational database *does not have indices*.

A purely theoretical relational database engine would indeed scan *all* records, check the criterion on the `sex` and `age` columns and only return the relevant rows.

However, indices are a common layer added by SQL database engines to filter rows faster. In this case, you should have indices for both of these columns.

What is more, these same database engines perform analysis on these indices (*if any*) to determine the best possible course of action to retrieve the relevant rows faster. In particular, one criterion in index metadata is [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29): for a given value of the indexed column, how many rows match on average? The higher the number of rows, the lower the cardinality. Therefore, the higher the cardinality the better.

Therefore, an SQL engine's query optimizer will certainly select to cut through the result set by looking up the `age` index first, and only then the index of `sex`. And it may even choose *not* to use the index on `sex` at all if it determines that it can be faster by just looking up the `sex` column value for each row resulting from the first filter. Which is likely here, since the cardinality of the `sex` column is ridiculously low.

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) for an introduction to the relational model.