# Does the order of indexes matter?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say you have a table with columns A and B, among others. You create a multi-column index (A, B) on the table.

Does your query have to take the order of indexes into account? For example,

```
select * from MyTable where B=? and A in (?, ?, ?);
```

In the query we put B first and A second. But the index is (A, B). Does the order matter?

**Update**: I do know that the order of indexes matters *significantly* in terms of the leftmost prefix rule. However, does it matter which column comes first in the query itself?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043042/does-the-order-of-conditions-in-a-where-clause-affect-mysql-performance , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035760/does-the-order-of-fields-in-a-where-clause-affect-performance-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case no but I recommend to use the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) keyword and you will see which optimizations MySQL will use (or not).

Answer (score 2):

The order of columns in the index can affect the way the MySQL optimiser uses the index. Specifically, MySQL can use your compound index for queries on column A because it's the first part of the compound index.

However, your question refers to the order of column references in the query. Here, the optimiser will take care of the references appropriately, and the order is unimportant. The different clauses must come in a particular order to satisfy syntax rules, so you have little control anyway.

Mysql reference on multi-column index optimisation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can test out specific queries of you think they are problems, but otherwise I wouldn't worry about this optimization.  Your query will mostly likely be mangled from its original form by the query plan.  That is to say MySQL should do a good job of planning how it will use the indices to optimize speed.  This may require the conditions to be in a different order, but I doubt it.  If MySQL actually did have to reorder the conditions for optimization it would be a very minor cost relative to the execution of the query (at least if the result set is large).