# MySQL WHERE OR: if first condition is true, the second is executed?

Tags: mysql

There is some another question about, but i didn't have still understand this despite all answers. The question is,
in a query like this:

```
select * from table WHERE userid = userid OR username = username
```

if is found true the first condition,
*userid = userid*
, mysql follow to test also the second condition *OR username = username*
??? or NOT?
I think yes, but would like to know as i can't find out an answer on any documentation.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the order of conditions in a WHERE clause affect MySQL performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043042/does-the-order-of-conditions-in-a-where-clause-affect-mysql-performance)

Answer (score 7):

There is no "first condition" and "second condition".  MySQL can choose to execute the conditions in whichever order it wants.  A SQL query represents the *result set*, not the specific processing steps.

That said, if multiple conditions are connected by `or` or `and`, then MySQL will "short-circuit" the evaluation and stop when it knows the answer.

The documentation is a bit weak on this point (it doesn't explain it exactly).  So, it is possible that MySQL (unlike virtually every other SQL database and compiler) does not short-circuit when possible.  [Here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/databases/threads/421598/mysql-short-circuit-where) is a blog where the author actually did a test on this; so there is at least one instance where the compiler appears to short-circuit the evaluation.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, It is strange that MySQL not provide any documentation about. When you say "There is no "first condition" and "second condition"", and so "A SQL query represents the result set", by the way, if this is the result, somewhere MySQL check for true or false. But into a table, could exist two records, which one match the first and the second match maybe the second one. So i think mysql should normally check for both?

Comment: @axew3 . . . For instance, MySQL might use an index on the second condition "first" and then check the first condition after using the index.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. i've think after, if the first one is an unique key, than maybe will not follow to check further more?

Comment: @axew3 . . . Unique keys are implemented using indexes.  So, yes, if MySQL can use the index then the second condition won't be checked for non-matching rows.

Comment: Gordon ... It is very clear now. Sorry that i maybe misunderstand often the right sense of words, due to my bad English, You answers had take me on the right way and let me well understand all what i was asking for. Thank you!!